# angular 9 + .net core 3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

i, trying to write a simple CRUD app, and getting the error : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
trying to call the server :

```
 getPersons(): Observable<Array<Person>> {

     return this.httpService.get<Array<Person>>(this.serverUrl + '/GetAllPersons',{headers: this.Headers});

Headers: any = { withCredentials: true, responseType: 'json', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };
```

the break point in the server doesn't stop in:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("GetAllPersons")]
        public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPersons()
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<Person> personArray = this.GetAllRecordsFromDB();
                return personArray;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
```

thanks

Comment: Do you get a `CORS` related error in the console?

Comment: As Mendy said, if your call is correct, you probably didn't enable CORS requests. in your startup.cs file, add `services.AddCors();` to your configureService() method.

Comment: this is my configure : i do have enable cors. public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");
            app.UseAuthorization();
         
            app.UseMvc();
        }

Comment: @Mendy i don't have a cors error in th console

Comment: this question certainly needs better explanation and more code (formatted code). Please edit the question and include more information.